# Comparison between operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have found the following two concepts:

$\bullet$ Let $L$ be a linear operator in a Hilbert space $H$. The
operator $B$ is said to be $L$-compact if $D(L)\subset D(B)$
and for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a constant $C_{\varepsilon}>0$ such that $$\|Bf\| \leq
\varepsilon \|Lf\|+ C_{\varepsilon}\|f\|\,\,\forall f \in D(L).$$

$\bullet$ Let $L$ be a linear operator in a Hilbert space $H$. The
operator $B$ is said to be is fully subordinate
to the operator $L$ if $D(L)\subset D(B)$
and if for every sufficiently
small  $\varepsilon>0$, $$\|Bf\| \leq
\varepsilon \|Lf\|+ \phi_{\varepsilon}(f) \,\,\forall f \in D(L)$$ 
where $\phi_{\varepsilon}$ is a continuous convex functional of $x \in H$.

My question is: is there an implication between these two concepts?

Comment: One implication should be quite clear. And I would not call the first concept "compact", there is already a different thing denoted like that in the literature.

Comment: I agree with @AndrasBatkai. Also, user45340, when you say you found the following two concepts, do you mean that you saw then somewhere, or that you came up with them?

Comment: I have found the first in "On an Unconditional Basis of Generalized Eigenvectors
of the Nonself-adjoint Gribov Operator in
Bargmann Space"
Marie-Thérèse Aimar, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications 231, 588-602 (1999).
and I found the second in the book "LINEAR DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS IN BANACH SPACE" by S. G. KREIN
AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY (1971)

Comment: what's the clear implication? the first implies the second or the second implies the first? and why?

Comment: what's about my question:the first implies the second or the second implies the first? and why?